# Fluent UI DocumentCardTitle global html attributes

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

Looking to add an id ([a global attribute on HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes))
to the DocumentCardTitle component to use for adding accessibility attributes such as aria-describedby

Something like this.

```
      <DocumentCardDetails className={styles.details}>
        <DocumentCardTitle
          className={styles.title}
          title={localizedTitle}
          id="action-desc"
        />
        <DocumentCardTitle
          title={localizedDescription}
          className={styles.description}
          showAsSecondaryTitle
        />
        <ActionButton
          aria-describedby="action-desc"
          onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) =>
            handleClick(e, props.item)
          }
          className={styles.button}
          text={callToActionLabel}
        />
      </DocumentCardDetails>
```

Error
[image: Error message thrown]

Is there a way to add this id or an alternative solution to adding accessibility properties?